# curl with a random proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm going insane trying to figure out what is the problem but I can't find it.

```
$proxies = loadProxies(5);

function getData($proxylist)
{
    $rand_proxy = rand(0,count($proxylist)-1);
    $url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'; //just for example
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.233.0 Safari/532.4";
    $referer = "http://www.google.com/";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxylist[$rand_proxy]);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
}

getData($proxies);
```

It **should** fetch a random proxy IP from the array and then use it in cURL request. All data I'm getting is a blank page. In some cases, I get infinite page load with no results whatsoever. What is causing this and how do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is with your loadProxies(5) return? cus this code works fine right here right now:

```
<?php 
$proxies = array('86.188.142.244:8080'); // random public http proxy

function getData($proxylist)
{
    $rand_proxy = rand(0,count($proxylist)-1);
    $url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'; //just for example
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.233.0 Safari/532.4";
    $referer = "http://www.google.com/";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxylist[$rand_proxy]);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($data!==true){$ex=new RuntimeException('curl_exec error. errno: '.curl_errno($ch).' error: '.curl_error($ch));@curl_close($ch);throw $ex;}
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo $data;
}

getData($proxies);
```

also, $data just returns the return code for curl, not the data, because, by default, curl outputs the response body to stdout. if you set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , it will return the body. (to redirect it to something else, use CURLOPT_FILE )

Comment: `$proxylist = loadProxies(2);
var_dump($proxylist);` returns `array(2) { [0]=> string(34) "47.88.104.219:80" [1]=> string(36) "14.161.21.170:8080" } ` so that is correct. When I type them manually into _CURLOPT_PROXY_, it works, but not when it's a variable.